# How do I convert this cURL terminal request to a PHP one?

Tags: php, curl, goinstant

This is for GoInstant, and I can't seem to convert it to a PHP cURL request.

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "value": { "type": "hot dog", "topping": "mustard" }, "options": { "expire": 15, "cascade": "relish" } }' \
https://api.goinstant.net/v1/keys/1/1/food/1
```

This is what I've got:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.goinstant.net/v1/keys/1/1/food/1");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('value' => array('foo' => 'hello!'))));
  $stuff = curl_exec($ch, true);
  echo $stuff;
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the request must be a PUT request, remove

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

and use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

Comment: This looks good to us! Let us know if you have any other questions.